# Reference attribute of element that is embedded in canvas (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to reference the source image of a Rectangle object in a canvas. I don't seem to find the correct code that will correctly reference it. Trying with ids doesn't work because the rectangle cant be given an id, only a group. Therefore, I need to use a group, but this is complex because I have several embedded attributes. Can anyone help? The current solution using `self.canvas.get_group("firstQelement")[0].source` I found online when a user had an issue with a similar problem. I have tried using different paths to get to the group, including referencing ids and layouts.

`AnswerCycle` refers to a pre formatted toggle button

Kivy File:

```
<QuestionDisplay>:
    name: "questionDisplay"
    RelativeLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#90E0EF')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    GridLayout:
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        Title: 
            id: questionTitle
        Image:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0077B6')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            id: mainQuestion
            source: "empty.png"
            size_hint_y: None
            size: root.width, 195
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            size: root.width, 200
            cols: 2
            AnswerCycle:
                id: firstQ
                canvas.after:
                    Rectangle
                        group: "firstQelement"
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "empty.png"
            AnswerCycle:
                id: secondQ
                canvas.after:
                    Rectangle
                        group: "secondQelement"
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "empty.png"
            AnswerCycle:
                id: fourthQ
                canvas.after:
                    Rectangle
                        group: "thirdQelement"
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "empty.png"
            AnswerCycle:
                id: thirdQ
                canvas.after:
                    Rectangle
                        group: "fourthQelement"
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "empty.png"
```

Python Code:

```
if Value.correctButtonNumber ==  1: self.canvas.get_group("firstQelement")[0].source = "cAnswer.png"
if Value.correctButtonNumber ==  2: self.canvas.get_group("secondQelement")[0].source = "cAnswer.png"
if Value.correctButtonNumber ==  3: self.canvas.get_group("thirdQelement")[0].source = "cAnswer.png"
if Value.correctButtonNumber ==  4: self.canvas.get_group("fourthQelement")[0].source = "cAnswer.png"
```

Error:

```
if Value.correctButtonNumber ==  1: self.canvas.get_group("firstQelement")[0].source = "cAnswer.png"
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random

APP_KV = """
<CanvasTest>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.after:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                group: 'rectangle'
                size: 400, 200
                pos: self.pos
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Ellipse:
                group: 'ellipse'
                size: 200, 100
                pos: self.pos
"""

class CanvasTest(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.BoxLayout.canvas.after.get_group('rectangle'))
    
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(APP_KV)
        return CanvasTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

When `BoxLayout:` is removed, from both the KV script and the print statement, this code works correctly.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks for the response, I have added this example, please find it at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that changes the `source` attribute of the `Rectangle`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

APP_KV = """
<CanvasTest>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        canvas.after:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                group: 'rectangle'
                size: 400, 200
                pos: self.pos
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
            Ellipse:
                group: 'ellipse'
                size: 200, 100
                pos: self.pos
"""


class CanvasTest(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.info, 2)

    def info(self, dt):
        rect = self.ids.box.canvas.after.get_group('rectangle')[0]
        rect.source = 'tester.png'


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(APP_KV)
        return CanvasTest()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

I added the `id` of `box` to the `BoxLayout` in the `APP_KV` to allow access to that `BoxLayout`. Note that you shouldn't try to access `ids` in the `__init__()` method because they typically have not been set yet at that point. That is why I used `Clock.schedule_once()`.